# Creating axes with irregular ticks

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create an axis that holds week numbers. However I can't use a normal time scale because the axis obeys a special rule:

> For each year, week 1 starts on the first day of the week

This means that at the end of each year, there may be days that form a partial week, after which the new year begins with week 1 again:

[image]

Can this be made using a d3 time axis, and thus benefit from all the axisy goodness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `tickFormat` function. Here's an example comparing the default formatting with week of year formatting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}


.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.axis text {
  font-size: 10px;
}

</style>
<body>

<h4>Week of Year Example</h4>

<div id="svg"></div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var hEach = 40; // height for each axis
var width = 960,
    height = 2*hEach;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    // month starts from 0!
    .domain([new Date(2015, 11, 1), new Date(2016, 0, 30)])
    .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

// Week of year
var xAxis_woy = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.weekOfYear)
    .orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("#svg").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")

var gx = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (.5*hEach) + ")")

    .call(xAxis);

var gx_woy = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (1.5*hEach) + ")")
    .call(xAxis_woy);


</script>
```

[Output](http://bl.ocks.org/adilapapaya/534a3f28bea5b6053175):

[image]

You can read more about `d3.time` [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals), and `.tickFormat` [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat)

Comment: Hi @adilapapaya - thanks for this. But your 1-tick is under January 3; should be January 1. This isn't a question about how to format a tick label.

Comment: @RobertGrant You can pass any function to `.tickFormat`...just replace `d3.time.weekOfYear` above with your own custom version which takes in a `Date` object and outputs the label to your specification. I think you can accomplish what you want using that in combination with specifying the `.tickValues` (so your ticks go Jan 01, Jan-08, ...)

Comment: Hm, I see what you mean. Sorry about the previous message - you're probably right. I'll give it a try!